# How to add non additive calculated measures in ssis

Tags: ssis, measure

I have 3 non additive measure that were calculated in derived column transformation.Now, I did the aggregate transofrmation to sum up my additive measure as the the last 3 I didnt put them in the aggregate but when I was trying to insert my measure to fact table those last 3 didn't show up ! How to insert them in the fact table should I use another transofrmation and what is it ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Aggregate Transformation does not allow you access to non-aggregated data.

Your best be would be to move the derived column transformation after the aggregate transformation. Otherwise, I covered how to access that data in my response on this question [Using SSIS, How do I find the cities with the largest population?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080979/using-ssis-how-do-i-find-the-cities-with-the-largest-population/8082874#8082874)