# How to merge new aggregated columns

Tags: ssis

I am trying to merge two tables after an aggregation transformation. Since I want few columns to pass through. Could someone suggest the transformation I need to use. Merge and Merge Join I am not able to use since I have 12489 rows from one output and 241 rows from another output. I want to add these aggregated values as just separate columns not related to previous columns.

[image: Transformations used]
[image: Aggregated output]
[image: Desired output]
[image: Source]

Comment: Your question will be improved with samples of your data after the Unpivot and the aggregate and how you expect them to look for the target table.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to keep all the original data and tie it to some aggregated values, this will be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080979/using-ssis-how-do-i-find-the-cities-with-the-largest-population again

Comment: You can do pretty much anything with a script transformation.

Comment: hello billinkc. I dont want to merge them .I want the aggregated values as a different columns in the destination table.

Comment: Since you're not supplying data, let me make guesses. Source has 3 detail lines and you need to present the total amount per header id along with the actual detail amounts. Thus Header ID 10: Detail 20 Amount 2; Detail 30 Amount 3; Detail 40 Amount 4. The desire it so show a column with 9 along side each of those rows. Is that similar to your request?

Comment: Remember, you are the one asking for help so the more you can do to explain the problem, the more likely you are to get it resolved. There is an Edit button above that will allow you to expand upon what you are attempting to do with concrete details

Comment: Source table cloumns are empname, country, age, gender, Question,Response (11200 rows)
Aggregate transformation output columns are Questions and their responses (260)I
In the destination I want all the columns from source table (empname, country, age, gender, Question,Response) and Columns of Aggregated output (Questions and their responses) extra columns they are not related to columns (Questions and Responses) of Source table.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to add images to comments section

Comment: Click the [edit button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv3AW.png). Comments are ephemeral